# Should (testing data read+write to sqlite database) be considered as integration or unit testing?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, integration-testing, functional-testing

Suppose, there is a class UserAccount with the following login, register, logout public methods. And suppose app stores user data inside local sqlite database. If I'm testing every of those three methods as separate tests then it's definitely unit tests. But if I want to have separate tests, like test if login method has correctly wrote data to sqlite database, then should such test be considered as integration test or as unit test?

Here's a list of our currently used terminology for testing:

1. Unit tests: for testing small units (class object methods). Planned to use technologies: XCTests
2. Integration tests: for testing outside app interaction like real webservices, facebook. Planned to use technologies: to be done on backend side (not duplicated on Android, and iOS).
3. UI tests: for testing separate screens. At some degree we may call it unit test as we are planning to test separate screen individually with mocked data. However, it's about testing UI controls within the screen. Planned to use technologies: Kif or UI Automation.
4. Functional tests: for simulating user interaction - tapping on screen buttons, navigating between screens and etc. Planned to use technologies: Calaba.sh

Personally, I think if every test for testing database read/write is about testing one write/read to particular database table then it also might be considered as unit test. Otherwise we will end up in calling "unit test" for every test testing one method, and calling "integration test" for everything that goes beyond the scope of particular method (even for functional tests).

PS. it would be also great to hear what kind of terminology you are using.

Comment: Does it matter what it's called?  I would say it's a unit test; just the unit is bigger than some other units.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. A question like this belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com, not stack overflow.